# How can I set my Airflow DAG to wait for Dataflow jobs to complete?

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-dataflow, airflow

I have a DAG that executes 3 Dataflow pipelines. I have set the dependency as such:

```
a > b > c
```

I have set the following default arguments:

```
default_dag_args = {
   'start_date': yesterday,
   'depends_on_past': True,
   'wait_for_downstream': True
}
```

However, it seems like all 3 pipelines are being scheduled at the same time.  How can I set pipeline b to run only after pipeline a finishes? And similarly pipeline c to only run after pipeline b finishes?

Update:

I changed it to:

```
a >> b >> c
```

Now it seems that a will kick off and complete, but b never begins. The DAG is active ("On").  Task a is still in a state of 'running' on Airflow, but in Dataflow the job has completed.  How do I get Airflow to recognize the Dataflow job has completed and proceed with task b?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if that's pseudocode, but your dependency should look like this (if you're talking about operators):

```
a >> b >> c
```

In the graph view, do lines appear between a --- b, and b --- c?  If the dependency is not set properly you will see all three of those operators just 'on the graph' without lines, and they will therefore be scheduled together.

If you want each DAG to complete one at a time, then set

```
max_active_runs=1
```

in the `DAG()` definition (not default args).

> max_active_runs defines how many running concurrent instances of a DAG there are allowed to be.

Finally another thing you can do - create [a pool with 1 slot](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#pools) and assign this DAG to that pool.

Comment: Now it seems that a will kick off and complete, but b never begins. The DAG is active ("On"). Task a is still in a state of 'running' on Airflow, but in Dataflow the job has completed. How do I get Airflow to recognize the Dataflow job has completed and proceed with task b?

Comment: [Melissa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10335909/melissa-guo), have you tried setting the triggering rule of operators b and c to ALL_DONE? `trigger_rule=trigger_rule.TriggerRule.ALL_DONE`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following `default_dag_args`:

```
default_dag_args = {
   'start_date': yesterday,
   'depends_on_past': False,
   'wait_for_downstream': True
}
```

`depends_on_past` flag would actually look for the previous run of the same task. So if the previous task instance failed, this task doesn't run. Example: If Task A was run yesterday and it failed, and now it is run today as well, it won't run if `depends_on_past: True`.

> depends_on_past: when set to true, task instances will run sequentially while relying on the previous task’s schedule to succeed. The task instance for the start_date is allowed to run.